# Third Party SMS/MMS app - import contact info vs. read contact info

Tags: mobile, sms, mms, messenger

Is it better for a third party messaging app to import all contact info or just read it when ever it needs to.  So many different apps have a different procedure here, and it spurred a bit of a debate.